# Blenders node editor draws boxes when I try to connect nodes

Tags: node-editor, interface

For some unknown reason, when I try to connect 2 nodes, from the cycles node group editor, I cannot draw a line, but instead it draws a select box what can I do against it?

I'm unable to progress my work now as I cannot finish the shader work, I cannot make a screenshot about it, its just as when one would make a group and had typed <kbd>B</kbd> (only I don't start with that crosshair cursor)

Blender 2.8x

Comment: Can you make sure, that there are (1) no conflicting addons enabled, (2) no keys stuck on your keyboard [restart your system] and (3) no pheripheral devices connected, which might send extra signals (like a drawing tablet) ?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to join nodes is to <kbd>Shift</kbd> click the two you want to connect and press <kbd>F</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

It's a confirmed bug in Blender, it happens on Windows with two monitors and each uses a different zoom scale, to solve use only 1 node editor pannel or use one monitor.

a case has been made on the bugtracker.